# How to get Rust contract methods to output/print when running on substrate-contracts-node?

Tags: rust, substrate-contracts-node, cargo-contract

I have tried following instructions from:

https://rustrepo.com/repo/paritytech-substrate-contracts-node

and

https://ink.substrate.io/faq/#how-do-i-print-something-to-the-console-from-the-runtime

My process:

1 - Add debug statements to the contract code:

```
#[ink(constructor)]
pub fn new() -> Self {
  ink_env::debug_println!("created new instance at {}", Self::env().block_number());
  Self {}
}

#[ink(message)]
pub fn sayhello(&self) {
  ink_env::debug_println!("Hello");
}
```

2 - build:  `cargo +nightly contract build`.

OUTPUT:

```
Original wasm size: 32.7K, Optimized: 11.1K

The contract was built in DEBUG mode.

Your contract artifacts are ready. You can find them in:
/home/IamDeveloper/MySoftwareProjects/blockchain/rust/rust-substrate-blockchain-projects/my-first-substrate-projects/my-first-project-prep-lesson/my-first-smart-contracts/helloworld/target/ink

  - helloworld.contract (code + metadata)
  - helloworld.wasm (the contract's code)
  - metadata.json (the contract's metadata)
```

3 - In another terminal, run the node:

```
substrate-contracts-node --dev -lerror,runtime::contracts=debug
```

4 - In the original terminal, upload:

```
cargo contract upload --suri //Alice
```

5 - Get the code hash:

```
code_hash=0xfd548906549af08bbb8bdd436f46b457d2b6ea9f8b6610e9515b3c4e7fe22d9c
```

6 - Instantiate:

```
cargo contract instantiate \
  --gas 500000000000 \
  --constructor new \
  --suri //Alice \
  --code-hash $code_hash
```

7 - Get the Contract:

```
Contract=5E4V3mvaf2nYKLRJJMNhc6TXrM5GxNwsga4hESRPquCXEyu1
```

8 - Call:

```
cargo contract call \
  --gas 500000000000 \
  --message sayhello \
  --suri //Alice \
  --contract $Contract
```

RESULT:
No output at all from the terminal running the node.

Answer (score 1):

I have the following ink! message:

```rs
#[ink(message)]
pub fn say_hello(&self) {
    ink_env::debug_println!("Hello");
}
```

I run my node like this:

```
./target/release/substrate-contracts-node --dev -lerror,runtime::contracts=debug
```

If I call like this:

```
cargo contract call \
  --gas 500000000000 \
  --message say_hello \
  --suri //Alice \
  --contract 5HJSXhYLExB5KYCMXa95mKEUX4UXXsp8Up9rBLzR57PPwtkq
```

The following appears in my node logs:

```
2022-08-02 13:07:28.410 DEBUG tokio-runtime-worker runtime::contracts: Execution finished with debug buffer: Hello
```

Make sure your contract exists.

You should see it in https://polkadot.js.org/apps/#/contracts

Also, try deleting your contract and re-deploying. You may have an old contract there.